# Why theano scan works differently when the codes are nearly the same?

Tags: theano

The code below:

```
import theano
import numpy as np
from theano import tensor as T
h1=T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((1, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX))
s1=T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((1, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX))

def forward(input, h, s):
    return h, s
result, update=theano.scan(fn=forward, sequences=[T.arange(10)], outputs_info=[h1, s1], go_backwards=False)
print result[0].shape.eval()
```

have an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, 3D) (of Variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float32, (False, True, False)). You can try to manually convert IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float32, (False, True, False)).
```

But when I change 1 to any other number, for example:

```
h1=T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((2, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX))
s1=T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((2, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX))
```

It works fine.

I don't know what happened here. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this post: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2985

Passing a tensor whose shape includes 1 as a part of outputs_info when calling theano.scan fails unless those axes of shape 1 are unbroadcasted manually using tensor.unbroadcast. This is due to the different broadcasting pattern between the actual return from the inner function of scan and the corresponding one passed via outputs_info.

Try:

```
h1=T.unbroadcast(T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((1, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX)), 0)
s1=T.unbroadcast(T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros((1, 20), dtype=theano.config.floatX)), 0)
```

to make the first dimension unbroadcastable.

Comment: Just to clarify: tuzhaopeng's suggestion should be considered a temporary workaround. This was a bug introduced in version 0.7 which has since been fixed. If you're using the most recent version of Theano off Github, this workaround will not be required; the OP's code works without error in that version.